# ts-mocha requires "./foo" imports, while tsc requires "./foo.js" imports

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I'm writing a very simple TypeScript library, and I want to test it with Mocha.

My `tsconfig.json` is

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "ES6",
        "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    },
}
```

and I have a `tsconfig.build.json` for transpiling

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
        "lib"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "declaration": true,
    },
}
```

With `"moduleResolution": "nodenext"` I need to use `import x from "./foo.js"` to import other files. That works, and `tsc -p tsconfig.build.json` emits successfully.

I installed ts-mocha and created a test file, where I `import x from '../lib/format.js'`. That typechecks and lints successfully.

However, when I run `ts-mocha tests/*.test.ts`, I get

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/format.js'
```

If I switch it to `import x from '../lib/format'` it seems to work with ts-mocha, but typechecking in VS Code and linting start to complain.

```
Relative import paths need explicit file extensions in EcmaScript imports when '--moduleResolution' is 'node16' or 'nodenext'. Did you mean '../lib/format.js'?
```

The full repository is at https://github.com/FiloSottile/age.ts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ts-mocha` uses a very old version of `ts-node`. That version probably does not understand the `"moduleResolution": "nodenext"` configuration.

You can use `ts-node` directly without using `ts-mocha`.

```
$ npm install --save-dev ts-node
$ mocha --reguire ts-node/register tests/**/*.ts
```